# jQuery Basic Animation Logic

Tags: jquery, loops, cycle

I'm working on a feature for a web site with these basic steps:
1) Animate in the first image
2) Animate in the caption
3) Show both for a specified amount of time
4) Animate out the caption
5) Animate out the image
6) Move on to the next list item (unless it's the last, then loop)

I've written a function to show the image & caption, the timer to show until,  and the function to animate them out. I'm currently fighting with how to go about step #6 above.

Basic HTML structure is:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current">
        <img src="my_pic.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">This is my caption text.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="my_pic.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">This is my caption text.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="my_pic.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">This is my caption text.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My Basic (informal syntax) Script is:

```
showCurrentListItem(); //Call the function that animates in the image & caption

setTimeout(function () { //Add a timer (Show for 5 seconds)
    hideCurrentListItem() //After 5 seconds, animate out the current list item
}, 5000)
```

I guess my main question is; how can I go about showing, then hiding the next list item after this first one completes? (& then resetting so that it loops once the last list item is reached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try it out with loop, something like :

```
var i = 0;
function ShowItem(){ // i be the index of image
// Write your code to animate
// image and caption
setTimeout(function(){ HideListItem(); }, 5000);
}

function HideItem(){
// Write Logic to Hide
// Image and Caption
i++;
if(i == 3) {// or whatever is the total count
i=0;
}
ShowItem();
}
```

Comment: It looks like in this example that 'i' is being passed into the HideItem() function. Would this require me to loop through the list items and assign them to an array so that they can be targeted using 'i' or am I overcomplicating this?

Comment: well, you dont need to pass i, i just change my code. Moreover, you get get li of any index by $("li").eq(i)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.current').hide().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        height: "toggle"
    }, 5000, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```